# Euler Tour in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am wondering what is wrong in the below C# code to produce an Euler Tour of vertex indices through Hierholzer's Algorithm, assuming all vertices have even degrees so the tour can start anywhere:

(and where pt_id is a list of list of integers representing the start and end point indices that made up of the edges)

ps. the GraphMatrix comprises of the following items initially, in case it is of any help due to the lack of information on pt_id:

```
n y y n y y n n n n n

y n n n y n n n n n n

y n n y y y n n n n n

n n y n n y n y y n n

y y y n n y n n n n n

y n y y y n n n n n n

n n n n n n n y y y y

n n n y n n y n y n y

n n n y n n y y n n y

n n n n n n y n n n y

n n n n n n y y y y n
```

---

code:

```
Stack tempPath = new Stack();
ArrayList finalPath = new ArrayList();

int total = 11;//total number of nodes

string[] nodeList = new string [total];//to store the nodes
string[,] GraphMatrix = new string [total, total];//to store the edge representation of graph

//node/vertice to nodeList array
for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
  nodeList[i] = i.ToString();
}


//edge details in the graph(connectivity boolean matrix)
//matrix first filled with "n"
for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
  for(int j = 0; j < total; ++j) {
    GraphMatrix[i, j] = "n";
  }
}
//if connection exists, matrix item is changed to "y"
for(int i = 0; i < pt_id.Count; ++i) {
  GraphMatrix[pt_id[i][0], pt_id[i][1]] = "y";
  GraphMatrix[pt_id[i][1], pt_id[i][0]] = "y";
}


//start tour

int s = 0;
int ind = 0;
tempPath.Clear();

tempPath.Push(nodeList[0]);

while(tempPath.Count != 0 && s < 100) {

  int index = 0;
  while (tempPath.Peek().ToString() != nodeList[index] && s < 100) {
    index++;
    s++;
  }

  ind = index;
  for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
    if(GraphMatrix[ind, i] != "y") {
      finalPath.Add(tempPath.Pop());
    }
    else{
      GraphMatrix[ind, i] = "n";
      GraphMatrix[i, ind] = "n";
      tempPath.Push(nodeList[i]);
    }
  }
  s++;
}
```

I am getting the error saying that the Stack is empty.

Thank you very much,

Tim

Comment: So, have you used a debugger to follow that stack? Or used system outputs to do the same?

Comment: Hi @Aziuth thanks for the response - am currently trying to in VisualStudio, but still don't quite get it.

Comment: Then I'd advice you to find some tutorial about debugging. Maybe a video that does an example. The system output approach would be to insert outputs to isolate the part where the bug happens, to trace the program (what it does when how many times etc) and in your context to print out the size of the stack whenever that should change. Trying to find out when the source of the bug first occured. Another thing you can do is to make everything smaller and then add stuff. Like only initializing the stack, then pushing one element, then... until the bug happens or the program works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to go through all elements of the stack in the line

```
  while (tempPath.Peek().ToString() != nodeList[index] && s < 100) {
```

but `Peek()` only returns the element on top of the stack without removing it. So in that line you will compare the element on top of the stack against the elements in `nodelist`.

To iterate over all elements in the Stack you can do

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var element in tempPath)
{
    if (element.ToString() == nodelist[index] && s >= 100)
    {
         break;
    }
    else 
    {
         index ++;
         s++;
    }
}
```

There is a second problem with your code.
Before calling `tempPath.Pop()` you need to check if there are any items left and do something else that your algorithm requires instead of calling `Pop()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I am still getting the error that the stack is empty.